# how to deploy multiple virtual machines using custom image?

Tags: image, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am using a Azure.
I created a custom image of Linux virtual machine.
I have to create multiple virtual machines of a custom image.
BUT I don't know the way to do.
In Resource manager portal, 'virtual machine scale out' function is only for OS images (not for custom images).
I prefer a solution done in the portal though, using Azure CLI or using template is okay to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an azure-quickstart-template named [201-vmss-windows-customimage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage) that will give you a template to achieve your scenario.

From the readme.md

> The template allows a URL to a custom image to be provided as a
>   parameter at run time. The custom image should be contained in a
>   storage account which is in the same location as the VM Scale Set is
>   created in, in addtion the storage account which contains the image
>   should also be under the same subscription that the scale set is being
>   created in.

Update: If your custom image is based on Linux, you need modify `osType` in this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage/azuredeploy.json#L241). Modify it to `Linux` and save it as name `test.json`. You could execute following cmdlet.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName mygroup -TemplateFile C:\Users\shui\Desktop\test.json
```

This is my test in my lab.

[image]

Also, you could use this [Deployment template for autoscaled custom image vmss](https://github.com/Signiant/azure-vmss-linux-custom)

> This template allows you to deploy an autoscaled VM Scale Set of Linux
>   VMs based of an existing custom image. The load balancers and vms
>   should be assigned public IPs

Comment: is it also for Linux? is it working for Linux? The template is for window

Comment: @user2275911 No, you need modify `osType` in this template. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user2275911 Hi, I find a good [template](https://github.com/Signiant/azure-vmss-linux-custom). You could use Powershell to generate a task.